# Regex to remove trailing whitespace and multiple blank lines

Tags: c#, .net, regex, visual-studio-2013

I'd like regex expressions to use in a Visual Studio 2013 extension written in C#.

I'm trying to remove trailing whitespaces from a line while preserving empty lines. I'd also like to remove multiple empty lines. The existing line endings should be preserved (generally carriage return line feed).

So the following text (spaces shown as underscores):

```
hello_world__


___hello_world_
__
__
hello_world
```

Would become:

```
hello_world

___hello_world

hello_world
```

I've tried a number of different patterns to remove the trailing spaces but I either end up not matching the trailing spaces or losing the carriage returns. I haven't yet tried to remove the multiple empty lines.

Here's a couple of the patterns I've tried so far:

```
\s+$

(?<=\S)\s+$
```

Comment: Do use strictly need to use RegEx? there is better way to remove simbols at string ends: TrimEnd and TrimStart. For your situation: str.TrimEnd(new char[] { '_' })

Comment: I don't strictly need to use regex, but I think it suits what I want to do. Maybe I should have elaborated, but I'm applying this to the active document. I am using C#. This doesn't have to be done in a single operation; multiple operations is fine.

Comment: It would be harder to do this in a single operation. However, they are 2 distinct operations and you don't need 1 to do the other either.

Comment: Regex is *considerably* slower than `TrimEnd`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the answers so far. None of them are quite right for what I need, but they've helped me come up with what I needed. I think the issue is that are some oddities with regex in VS2013 (see [Using Regular Expressions in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.120).aspx)). These two operations work for me:

Replace `\ +(?=(\n|\r?$))` with nothing.

Replace `^\r?$(\n|\r\n){2,}` with `\r\n`.

Comment: VS2013 uses Dot-Net regex engine, not really odd. Just a fyi, Microsoft (eg. Windows) use CRLF translation in all their edit boxes they supply an api for. Therefore your regex's don't make sense. Finally, you ripped off my expressions, answered the question yourself, then marked it as correct.

Comment: None of the answers anyone gave actually worked for me as they are. They're all good regex and work well in the online regex testers, but they didn't work for me in .NET or the VS find replace tool. I posted an answer because I wanted to leave the question with an answer that works in my situation in case it was useful to someone else. Actually the regex to replace trailing whitespace is from @zolo with the modification suggested in the link I provided. The regex to remove multiple blank lines I put together using several answers as inspiration.

Comment: I would check if Visual Studio actually uses _Dot-Net_ engine. Microsoft says it does. I'm really not sure what you mean when you say it didn't work since their engine is mostly a pcre engine missing recursion and having some class extra constructs, etc.. But none of that is involved here, none ..

Answer (score 1):

To remove multiple blank lines and trailing whitespace with

```
(?:\r\n[\s-[\rn]]*){3,}
```

and replace with `\r\n\r\n`.

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3A%5Cr%5Cn%5B%5Cs-%5B%5Crn%5D%5D*)%7B3%2C%7D&i=hello_world%20%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20hello_world%20%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0Ahello_world&r=%0D%0A%0D%0A)

And to remove the remaining whitespace, you can use

```
(?m)[\s-[\r]]+\r?$
```

See [demo 2](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3Fm)%5B%5Cs-%5B%5Cr%5D%5D%2B%5Cr%3F%24&i=hello_world%20%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20hello_world%20%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0Ahello_world%20%20%0D%0A%20%20hello%20world%201%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20hello%20worlds%202%20%20%20&r=)

Comment: Could you please explain this part to me? 
[\s-[\r]]

Comment: Yes. Character class subtraction is a .NETspecific feature. Using a negated character class is a workaround for those regex flavors that do not support class subtraction or intersection.

Answer (score 1):

```
\ +(?=(\n|$))
```

Any number of space, and checking that after a newline coming OR end of line (last characters in your string/text). (of course multi line needs to be enabled and global mode)

Comment: One thing, this will match `here\t\t\t\t` as well.

Comment: Perfectly right. I should use only "\ +" instead of "\s+". Thanks!

Comment: Then `\ +` won't let the regex match more than 1 line

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/fF1jE4/1
I don't understand what exactly do you mean. check here and let me know if I used it wrongly.

Comment: I'd say it wrong, you've set the global flag `//g`, its found 3 separate matches.

Comment: Yes, found all. What were you looking for?

Comment: It could be perfectly valid to find `\t` as well as `&#20`, or any of the other white space characters, I would present both options with an explanation.

Comment: Seems this one would do both, removing empty lines but keeping at least one, and deleting spaces at the end of the lines
`(^\ *\n(?=\ *$))|((?<=\S)\ +$)`
https://regex101.com/r/fF1jE4/3

Answer (score 1):

Just as a punt, without the use of Regex, you could always split the document by its end of line marker and then feedback using `TrimEnd` (as highlighted by Anton Semenov)...

(Assuming a text document read into a string...)

```
//  Ascertain the linefeed...
string str = "This is a test    \r\nto see if I can force   \ra string to be broken \non multiple lines           \r\n into an array.";
string[] t = str.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" } ,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
thediv.InnerHtml = str + "<br /><br />";
foreach(string s in t)
{
    thediv.InnerHtml += s.TrimEnd() + "<br />";
}
```

I haven't timed this at all, but if you prefer to avoid the complications of Regex (which I do if I can - see below*), you should find this fast enough to do what you want.

* I avoid Regex if I can. That doesn't mean that I don't use it. Regex has its place, but I believe it to be a last resort tool for involved jobs, for instance complex flexible strings that adhere to a format - something where the alternative will generate large amounts of code. Keeping Regex to an absolute minimum aids the readability of your code.

Answer (score 0):

The `\s` includes the linefeed, I would search for just multiple blanks instead. I do not know the specifics of VS, but this should hopefully do it:

```
[" "]*?$
```

Answer (score 0):

As separate operations -

Remove trailing whitespace any `(?m)[^\S\r\n]+$`
Remove trailing whitespace lines with text `(?m)(?<=\S)[^\S\r\n]+$`

Remove duplicate blank lines (along with whitespace trim)

```
    # Find: (?>\A(?:[^\S\r\n]*\r\n)+)|(?>\r\n(?:[^\S\r\n]*(\r\n)){2,})
    # Replace: $1\r\n


    (?>
         \A 
         (?: [^\S\r\n]* \r \n )+
    )
 |  
    (?>
         \r \n 
         (?:
              [^\S\r\n]* 
              ( \r \n )                     # (1)
         ){2,}
    )
```